# TCP Automatic Reconnect (Forever until user tells it to stop)

Tags: c#, tcp, reconnect

I have a way to tell the TCP client to connect over and over if a bool is true, but i don´t know if this really is a good way to do it, as i pretty much tells it to to it over and over, and ignore the errors.

But i also don´t know of any other way to do it.

But maybe you guys do, here is the part of the code:

```
 while (capcon == true)
    {

        using (tcp = new TcpClient())
        {
            tcp.NoDelay = true;
            try
            {
                if (!tcp.Connected)
                    tcp.Connect(adress);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e is SocketException || e is IOException) { }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message + " Tcp Connect : Send");

            }
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Stoptimer = new Stopwatch();
                int i = 0;
                while (tcp.Connected && capcon == true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FastMethods.CaptureBitBit(hwnd, JpegParam, jpeg, ms);
                        if (bsize != ms.Length && tcp.Connected)
                        {
                            bsize = ms.Length;
                            Stoptimer.Start();

                            tcp.GetStream().Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(bsize), 0, intsize);

                            tcp.GetStream().Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)bsize);
                            //i++;
                            //tcp.GetStream().Write(rv, 0, rv.Length);
                            if (i > 100)
                            {
                                i = 0;
                                Stoptimer.Stop();
                                Console.WriteLine(Stoptimer.ElapsedTicks);
                                Stoptimer = new Stopwatch();
                            }

                        }
                        ms.SetLength(0);

                    }

                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        if (e is SocketException || e is IOException)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(e.Message + ": Send Error");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Well, as you can see, it´s a mess, but it´s what i got.

Comment: You are missing the part where you actually stop trying to connect ( when connection is a success) ...

Comment: When it´s successful it will continue the code into another while loop, and there it does it´s stuff. And if the connection fail, it break;, making it run to the previous While loop, which tells it to Reconnect.

Comment: It's never a good idea to just ignore exceptions. Some indicate conditions that can be recovered from with a retry: some don't.

Comment: How can i tell it to just retry if it can? I only know SocketExeption and IOException, both seem to occur if a connection failed

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I would do it with nested while(), maybe break out the connection logic into a separate method and call it whenever needed but that is just preference for maintainability.
I would also look to log your socket-related exceptions, incase your disconnects are something you can fix (if you don't know what they are caused by, you have no hope of preventing them).

Are you noticing a performance issue or just requesting "best practice"?  [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be of interest if this is the case.

Comment: Could you show an example of how you would do it?
And well , why i have it like this is not caused by ant real issues itself, it´s just for, easiness/laziness. Hmm true, didn´t think of that.